# ULS logs filling up with Error: Failed to get document content data

Tags: 2013, javascript, error, sharepoint-on-prem, uls

Our Sharepoint farm's homepage constantly generates these "High" log items, making other debugging difficult. As far as I can tell, it doesn't acutally cause any problems.
Error:

```
High - Database
Failed to get document content data.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Cannot complete this function
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)
```

and after it

```
High - Files
Could not get DocumentContent row: 0x80004005.
```

These Errors occur every time an image is loaded from our homepage, which is a regular site page with some java-script that loads an Image into a img tag

```
$("#mainpic").attr("src", "/SiteAssets/Mission12.png");
```

I would like to figure out what is causing these errors so I can solve the problem.

Our Farm:

- SharePoint 2013 SP1
- Sept 2015 CU
- Server 2012 R2
- SQL 2014 SP1

**Update**
also occurs after moving to our new farm:

- SharePoint 2016
- Dec 2016 CU
- Server 2016
- SQL 2016

Comment: what browser you are using? if IE 11 then try with compatibility mode or try different browser...

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE This homepage is used by a large number of people, all using different OS/Browser combos.  The meta tag on the HTML page sets IE to use 10 mode (which is the default for SharePoint 2013)

Comment: Hi @Aaron, have you solved this problem? We also see a lot of this high log item.

Comment: No we lived with this will no ill effects until our move to sharepoint online.